# Move from *this in an rvalue method?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

In C++11, methods can be overloaded on whether or not the expression that denotes the object on which the method is called is an lvalue or an rvalue. If I return `*this` from a method called via an rvalue, do I need to explicitly `move` from `*this` or not?

```
Foo Foo::method() &&
{
    return std::move(*this);   // Is this move required or not?
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't simply test this on my compiler since g++ does not support this feature yet :(

Comment: I'd expect the `move` to be required, as `this` is a named rvalue, similar to if a function takes a rvalue parameter. But not making it an answer since I can't quote chapter and verse on it :)

Comment: @jalf: And I would expect the move to be required since generally `*E` is an lvalue, but who knows :) And I have never heard of named rvalues before. Are you sure about "this"? (no pun intended!)

Comment: A named rvalue is a new term introduced to disambiguate overloaded calls involving references. e.g. if we have `foo(X& x)` and `foo(X&& x)`, what does `foo(someX)` call, i.e is `someX` an `X&` or an `X&&`? The answer is `X&` because `someX` has a name -- it is a named rvalue, which is an `X&`. If we called `foo(someX + something)` then it would be an `X&&` because expressions don't have "names".

Comment: "is `someX` an `X&` or an `X&&`?" -> Erm, neither? It is an X :) I don't see how `someX` is anything but an lvalue...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of `*this` is *always* an lvalue:

`§9.3.2 [class.this] p1`

> In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the keyword **`this`** is a prvalue expression whose value is the address of the object for which the function is called. The type of **`this`** in a member function of a class **`X`** is **`X*`**. [...]

`§5.3.1 [expr.unary.op] p1`

> The unary **`*`** operator performs *indirection*: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and **the result is an lvalue** referring to the object or function to which the expression points.

So you will need to `std::move` if you want to invoke the move constructor.

The following code snippet shows that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct test{
  test(){}
  test(test const&){ std::cout << "copy ctor // #1\n"; }
  test(test&&){ std::cout << "move ctor // #2\n"; }

  test f_no_move() &&{ return *this; }
  test f_move() &&{ return std::move(*this); }
};

int main(){
  test().f_no_move(); // #1
  test().f_move(); // #2
}
```

Using Clang 3.1 (the only compiler I know that implements ref-qualifiers), I get the following output:

> $ clang++ -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ -pedantic -Wall t.cpp
>   $ ./a.out
>   copy ctor // #1
>   move ctor // #2