# What is "Extending move semantics to *this" all about?

Tags: c++, c++11, this, rvalue, move-semantics

Please, could someone explain in plain English what is "Extending move semantics to *this"? [I am referring to this proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2439.htm). All what am looking for is *what* is that & *why* do we need that. Note that I do understand what an rvalue reference is in general, upon which move semantics is built. I am not able to grasp what such an extension adds to rvalue references!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ref-qualifier feature (indicating the type of `*this`) would allow you to distinguish whether a member function can be called on rvalues or lvalues (or both), and to overload functions based on that. The [first version](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1821.htm) gives some rationale in the informal part:

> Prevent surprises:
>
> ```
> struct S {
>   S* operator &() &;            // Selected for lvalues only
>   S& operator=(S const&) &;     // Selected for lvalues only
> };
>
> int main() {
>   S* p = &S();                  // Error!
>   S() = S();                    // Error!
> }
> ```
>
> Enable move semantics:
>
> ```
> class X {
>    std::vector<char> data_;
> public:
>    // ...
>    std::vector<char> const & data() const & { return data_; }
>    std::vector<char> && data() && { return data_; } //should probably be std::move(data_)
> };
>
> X f();
>
> // ...
> X x;
> std::vector<char> a = x.data(); // copy
> std::vector<char> b = f().data(); // move
> ```

Answer (score 7):

For example, you can overload operators as free functions with rvalue references if you wish:

```
Foo operator+(Foo&& a, const Foo& b)
{
    a += b;
    return std::move(a);
}
```

To achieve the same effect with a member function, you need the quoted proposal:

```
Foo Foo::operator+(const Foo& b) &&   // note the double ampersand
{
    *this += b;
    return *this;
}
```

The double ampersand says "this member function can only be called on rvalues".

Whether or not you must explicitly move from `*this` in such a member function is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028632/move-from-this-in-an-rvalue-method).