# rvalue delegation, or the rvalue equivalent of a const member function

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue

```
struct that
{
    that &frob()
    {
        return *this;
    }
    that frob() const
    {
        return that(*this);
    }

    //that &&frob() && //<-called only if *this is an rvalue
    //{
    //    return move(*this);
    //}

    that()
    {
        // make things
    }
    that(const that &other)
    {
        // copy things
    }
    that(that &&other)
    {
        // move things
    }
};
```

Obviously the function in comments above is not legal C++, but I need to know if there is a way to accomplish this:

```
that().frob().frob().frob();
```

and so on, while each call to `frob()` would effectively call the "move" version thereof. As this is something that can be determined at compile time, I can't think of any reason for it to not exist in some form.

I can write something like this:

```
that &&frob(that &&t)
{
    return t;
}
```

Which would result in this:

```
frob(frob(frob(that())));
```

Which is somewhat annoying to read and doesn't accomplish my goal of "spelling things out" with delegation.

Comment: [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028632/)

Comment: Just to be pedantic, note that `*this` is *always* an lvalue. It's very tempting to confuse `*this` with "the implicit instance parameter".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `&&` annotated function to play well with others, you should use the `&` annotation on the others.

```
that &frob() &
{
    return *this;
}
that frob() const &
{
    return that(*this);
}
```

Comment: That is a compilation error using Intel C++ v12: `error: expected a ';'`.

Comment: @i_photon Hmm, that missing feature kills a lot of the usefulness of rvalue `this`. Sorry.

Comment: It seems to be the same for MSC as well :c

Comment: @i_photon ICC is one of the better ones… well it gets a similar error in GCC 4.7 but Clang 3.1 works fine, and does what you describe for `that().frob().frob().frob();`.

Comment: Actually, Clang is currently the only compiler to support rvalue for `*this`.

Comment: Looks like this weekend will involve poking around with Clang. Also, does anyone know if it supports `__declspec(property(...))`? I read something in a mailing list somewhere, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @i_photon that's not standard, that's an MSVC extension. I doubt clang supports it.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to determine if an object is an rvalue from within the object. The best you can do is copy it if it is `const` and move it if its not:

```
that frob() const
{
    return *this;
}

that frob()
{
    return std::move(*this);
}
```

**EDIT**

Further reaserch shows that you actually [can](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2439.htm), as @Potatoswatter pointed out, but its called ref-qualification and not annotation.